# I think I'm being stupid... but I can't get my JSON output properly

Tags: jquery, getjson, json

I'm trying to build a shopping cart.

There's very simple class which creates a `generic.dictionary(of string, generic.dictionary(of string, string)` this contains my cart items.

The keys for the intitial dictionary are the item Ids, so I can easily check whether the item is already in the cart using `cartDictionary.ContainsKey(id)` and then increment the quantity or add a new as required.

The BUY button triggers and AJAX-ified web method, which returns data looking like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "7907": {
            "id": "7907",
            "qty": "4",
            "singlePrice": "1185"
        },
        "2698": {
            "id": "2698",
            "qty": "1",
            "singlePrice": "1322"
        }
    }
}
```

The initial item `d` is created automatically by the AJAX post for reasons which I dont understand, but it doesnt really matter, my output is therefore `data.d` in my AJAX success, as follows:

```
success: function (data) {
    result = [data.d];
}
```

Now, from this I need to be able to get the inner data to present it into a shopping cart

So I need to be able to loop through the items by ID and extract

```
id
qty
singlePrice
```

So that I can display it in the browser, but I'm going cross eyed trying to work it out.

I've tried adding `[` around data.d, like

```
var result = [data.d]
```

and tried looping within the result like

```
result = [data.d];

    $(result).each(function (i, thing) {
         var thisOne = (result[i]);
         //alert(thing); //<< returns object object
         $(thisOne).each(function (j, val) {
              alert(thisOne + " - " + val.id); //<< both thisOne and val.id return object object
         });
     });
```

By the returns from the alerts I am clearing getting some kind of JSON objects, but I've obviously got something mixed up!

I'm no programmer, but working on a project which is slowly driving me crazy!!

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, use `console.log( ... )` instead of `alert` when debugging. You'll get a lot more information about what's going on, and it won't disappear as soon as you click "ok". The output will be in your DOM inspector's console (Firebug in Firefox, Developer Tools in Chrome/Safari/IE. Press F12 in any of the browsers to open their DOM inspector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
var data = {
    "d": {
        "7907": {
            "id": "7907",
            "qty": "4",
            "singlePrice": "1185"
        },
        "2698": {
            "id": "2698",
            "qty": "1",
            "singlePrice": "1322"
        }
    }
}



var result = data.d;

$.each(result , function(ind, el) {
    //alert(thing); //<< returns object object
    alert(ind + " - " + el.id);
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/VHPQX/

Comment: What's the outer `.each()` for?

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (data) {
    var d = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    for(var i =0;i<d.length;i++)
    {     
        alert("Id is"+d[i].id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery's [generic iterator `$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) rather than its jQuery object iterator `$().each()`:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d, function(k, val) {
       // "val" is the current item, so use its properties here, e.g.:
       var id = val.id,
           total = +val.qty * +val.singlePrice;
    });
}
```

(Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2vvfZ/)

Note that when iterating over an object's properties the order isn't guaranteed (and when I tested this in Chrome it did the 2698 item then the 7907 item). If you need to be sure of the order use an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for..in loop:

```
for (key in data.d)
{
    document.write(key + '<br>')
    document.write('<blockquote>')
    document.write('id: ' + data.d[key].id + '<br>')            
    document.write('qty: ' + data.d[key].qty + '<br>')            
    document.write('singlePrice: ' + data.d[key].singlePrice + '<br>')            
    document.write('</blockquote>')
}
```

Result:

```
2698
    id: 2698
    qty: 1
    singlePrice: 1322
7907
    id: 7907
    qty: 4
    singlePrice: 1185
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnqWK/